# "Message did not receive a reply" browsing iPad 2

Tags: ipad

I've installed `libimobiledevice` and wanted to browse through my iPad 2 4.3.5 iOS. But I get this error:

```
DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
```

A solution for Ubuntu 10.10, running `sudo apt-get update dist-upgrade`, didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you may need to unpair and pair your device..

Try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10205459&postcount=32

Originally Posted by DodgeV83

> The PPA by itself didn't work for me. I then had to run:
>
> ```
> idevicepair unpair
> idevicepair pair
> idevicepair validate
> ```
>
> Got the answer from the following Bug Reports
>
> - http://libiphone.lighthouseapp.com/projects/27916/tickets/183-cannon-mount-iphone-with-ios-421-in-ubuntu-1010#ticket-183-13
> - http://libiphone.lighthouseapp.com/projects/27916/tickets/181-cant-mount-iphone-in-ios-421#ticket-181-10
>
> Just remembering: to do that you need to have `libimobiledevice-utils`
>   installed, if you don't have it
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils
> ```